# How to label in html NOT with id?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

I am working on a React App in which it requires working with tables and adding rows dynamically. I used this answer to achieve that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54455262/13037132. I am trying to label an `<input type="file" id={id} />` for styling the whole
[image] in every cell of the table. The `id={id}` attribute in the input element is for dynamically adding a row when an `Add Row` button is clicked.

I found some solution for styling this input, but it requires labelling it, needs an `id` attribute to link to. How can I do that, since the id is already occupied? Is there a way to link this input to a label without using the id but something else? If you want any additional data on this, please let me know.

And I am also looking for a way to add columns too just like I am adding rows using the above-stated answer. Can anyone help?

Comment: Here you could use input[type="file"]. You need to read about CSS selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: I am not facing problems in styling but FOR styling, i.e. replacing the input with some image, I need to label my input element, in which I am facing problems as stated.

Comment: Does something prevent you from using a class or combination of classes?

Comment: No. Basically I need a way to link the label to input without using id, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use a class instead of id, since multiple id with same value does not help, use a class and access that input by $(this):

```
$('.class_name').click(function(){
    $(this) // this will acquire the clicked/target input
})
```